# GCD dispatch_io_read() intermittent under CPU strain

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, live-streaming

I'm building a macOS app (Objective-C) and in it I am using dispatch_io_read() to stream live data from a socket and it works great 99% of the time. However, if the computer happens to be under high CPU load (for other reasons) then the reads start to become delayed and “batched/buffered”, regardless if my application is in the foreground or not. For example, I am able to reproduce this by starting code compilation in the background while running my app. Sometimes I am not receiving any data for several seconds, only to then receive a burst of everything quickly.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Naturally I am assuming that my reads are of lower CPU priority than the other tasks on the system, but how could I possibly solve that?

I have tried using different dispatch queues etc, but it does not make a difference.

```
dispatch_io_read(dispatch_io_t channel,
    off_t offset,
    size_t length,
    dispatch_queue_t queue,
    dispatch_io_handler_t io_handler);
```

Comment: I'd try first to figure out if your bottleneck is really CPU or IO. What are you doing with the data? How do you process it? What's your desired expectation for this situation?

Comment: The data is an encoded video stream. I input the video stream into a VTDecompressionSession. I doubt the issue is IO-related, since if I change the bitrate the problem remains the same. For example, running 1MB/s or 30MB/s  both show the same issues. And when the CPU is not under strain, I see no issues at all with either.